# Delphi Seattle problemas com Sockets

Tags: delphi, socket, delphi-10

[Delphi Seattle] Tenho uma unit que tem uses no Sockets(de um fonte que estava no Delphi XE2), o uses não reconhece.. alguem sabe como proceder? Obs: Ai sem esse uses tenho mais problemas pois não reconhece o TCustomIpClient..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nao sei se é em todos mas no Tokyo a unica unit que tenho com essa class é a Web.Win.Sockets

Nao está no projecto por defeito (posso nao ter instalado algo com o IDE) mas está nos samples que vem com o IDE, algo como

```
C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\19.0\Samples\Object Pascal\VCL\InetWinSockets\Web.Win.Sockets.pas
```

Espero que ajude

Comment: Vou tentar sim.. Já tinha ouvido falar que tinha mudado, mas não sabia que a mesma não estava no projeto..

Answer (score 1):

A biblioteca não vem instalada por padrão, mas esta disponível nos fontes do Delphi.
Para isto basta instalar a `bpl`equivalente à versão que esta usando, geralmente esta na pasta bin.

Na versão Tokyo a bpl é a `dclsockets250.bpl` entenda que este *250* é a versão.

Fonte: [Embarcadero](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Installing_Socket_Components).

Comment: Já fiz isso, porém o uses ainda não é encontrado..